# Reading timing diagram of MBI5168

Tags: microcontroller, timing-analysis

I am studying this little IC called [MBI5168](https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/mbi5168.pdf). It is serial-to-parallel LED driver.

I don't get why OUT0, OUT1, and OUT7 are ON, when the 8 bit data latched in SDI shows 10100011b. Shouldn't this yield OUT0, OUT2, OUT6 and OUT7?

[image: Timing Diagram]

Comment: The data is shifted in msb first. So the N=0'th bit in is OUT7 and the N=7'th bit in is OUT0. They don't show OUT5, but that would be 'ON' too.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected there was an error in the diagram. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram doesn't include the signal outputs for Outputs 4 and 5. 10100011 is written into the device on the SDI line. Outputs 0,1,5 and 7 would be turned on by this number. As we don't see outputs 4 and 5 in the timing diagram, only outputs 0,1 and 7 are noted as on.